# Facing an issue while using existing Web service as wcf into VS 2012

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have one of webservice which as below method

```
    c.Accountdata ad = new  Accountdata();
    c.response res = ad.PostData(RequestData);
```

NOw, i have used above webservice into vs 2012 as add service reference so, it is added as a WCF SERVICE.

Now, i get below code.

```
   c.AccountdataSoapClient ad =new AccountdataSoapClient();
   c.response res = new c.response();
   ad.PostData(REQUESTHEADER,RequestData,out res).
```

//in above method, two argumnets are increased (HEADER AND OUT PARAMETER).

I have passed request header instance as it is not actually existed in web service.
NOW, PROBLEM: it throws CLIENT FAULT EXCEPTION.

please suggst me how i could use same web service into this VS 2012 and correct such issue.

not sure, how old webservice schema map into WCF.

Thanks

Comment: RequstData - typo in the first section.

Comment: just an object name. corrected. please suggest how it could resolve.

Comment: Sorry, mate. Usually, I create only WCF-styled web service references using VS and I get everything set up automatically. I let the "black magic" be done by the Visual Studio.   +1 for good questions, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

If your web service is an old-style web-service (not WCF) then you should add a reference to it by this old-services compatibility menu, and use it as you are used it before:
[image]